# How to extract two different nodes of an XML file

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have the following XMl file which I want to extract some nodes of it. I would like to extract two sets of nodes.

```
<root >
  <comment>
     // something here
  </comment>
  <define>
     // something here
  </define>
  <scrp>
     // something here
  </scrp>
  <files >
  <file id ="1" Name="S1">
    <file id ="2" Name="S11">
      <file id ="3" Name="S111" />
      <file id ="4" Name="S112" />
        <file id ="5" Name="S1121" />
    </file >
    <file id ="6" Name="S12" />
  </file >
</files>
</root >
```

I would like to extract all nodes `files` and `scrp` to a new `XML` file. I did as below code, but it will save only the `files` node not both nodes `files` and `scrp`. May I ask your help?

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlfile);
XElement files = doc.Descendants("files").FirstOrDefault();
XElement root = doc.Element("root");
doc.Element("root").ReplaceWith(new XElement("root", new object[] { pack.Attributes(), files }));
doc.Root.ReplaceNodes(new XElement("files", doc.Descendants("file")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the entire contents of the root node need to be replaced with the specific nodes then ReplaceAll on doc.Root should work. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
        var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlfile);
        XElement files = doc.Descendants("files").FirstOrDefault();
        XElement scrp = doc.Descendants("scrp").FirstOrDefault();
        doc.Root.ReplaceAll(scrp, files);
```